# Is there a more mobile friendly auth URL than "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"

Tags: facebook, mobile, authentication

I'm working on a mobile app, and it makes use of a server as a middle-man for various reasons. Since the mobile app never interfaces directly with facebook, the server handles all auth. (It is in Python.) Here's the flow:

1. The app asks for an auth URL, and the server sends it "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" with the appropriate parameters.
2. The app sends the user to the page, they navigate etc. and get to the code...
3. ...which they copy back to the app, which sends it to the server for authentication. (I'm going to factor this step out eventually.

The problem is that that particular URL juts looks dreadful on the iPhone. I've tried to find a mobile version (there must be one, right?) but nothing has come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried requesting "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize"?  You can add "&display=touch" to force the mobile version.